# how can I avoid use global variable in this code?

Tags: python

```
parse_client = None
store_client = None
def init_client():
    global parse_client
    global  store_client

    // ... some codes

    factory = ClientFactory(config)
    parse_client = factory.getJdParseClient()
    store_client = factory.getJdStoreClient()


def has_jd(jd_url):

    jd_id = parse_client.parseJdId(jd_source, jd_url)
    return store_client.listJd("", [jd_id])

def caculate(concurrency, jd_list):
    with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=concurrency) as executor:
        for jd_item in jd_list:
            job = executor.submit(check_url, jd_item)


def check_url(jd_item):
    jd_date, jd_source, url = jd_item
    return (jd_date, jd_source, url, has_jd(url))

def main():
    init_client()
    concurrency = 15

    jd_count, jd_item_list = parse_files()
    caculate(concurrency, jd_item_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want to know if I have better choice instead of the global variable `parse_client` and `store_client`.

The problem is if I change these two variable from global to local variable, I need to init them every time, but these two variable is generate by the `ClientFactory` which need `remote producedure call(rpc)`, so the  cost is too much

Comment: This question looks like it is somewhere between unclear and [generic/hypothetical](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/9357). You can make it clear and on-topic by describing what the code is about and retitling the question to reflect the purpose of the code, not how you want it reworked. (See [ask].)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a bunch of methods that need to work with the same data.
Instead of using global variables for the shared data,
a simple alternative can be wrapping these methods in a class.
You can initialize the shared data in the constructor,
and the methods will be able to access them via `self.parse_client` and `self.store_client`.
The code in the current `init_client` could be in the constructor,
and you can delete this function.